# Dynamic PHP URL Ajax Load URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Problem im retriving variables in PHP and want to give it to ajax to generate a mysql update.

```
$.ajax({
url: '../mysqlusercount.php?f=ll&users='<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
 },
});
```

This version doesnt work, anybody can help pls ?

Comment: try to add ; at the end of your $_SESSION['user']

Comment: does your ajax run in the main PHP file or external?

Answer (score 0):

incorrect line

```
url: '../mysqlusercount.php?f=ll&users='<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>,
```

should be

```
url: "../mysqlusercount.php?f=ll&users=<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>",
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the session variable outside of the JavaScript string. Try this:

```
url: "../mysqlusercount.php?f=ll&users=<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>"
```

Comment: is this right? would this be return a value for `users=<?php echo $_SESSION['users']?>` instead of the real value of the `$_SESSION` variable? . Its also same as what @adidi answered below.

Comment: @Kaii This is assuming the code is in a PHP file and going through the PHP parser. If it is in just a `.js` file then you will not get the actual value of the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: Oh i see forgot to think of it. Yes it didnt needed to be concatenate.. rofl

Answer (score 0):

Watch out HTTP Response for debugging.
FireBug(plugin of firefox or latest Firefox),Chrome.
Or get error message by using ini_set('display_errors', '1'); ...